# Why i see mixed information after upgrading from drupal 6.3 to 6.28

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

So i just upgraded from 6.3 to 6.28 and now in mysite/admin/reports/status i see mixed information.
In first line i see Drupal 6.28

But in line with drupal core update status, I see that update is needed and it says Not secure! (version 6.28 available). I guess that is a bit unlogical because i ahve that version!
All other messages are green. However on mysite/admin/reports/updates, I see all updates listed and saying drupal core 6.3, and suggesting i install 6.28. All other modules are updated.

Could i do something wrong? How to fix it?
Btw. The page is working normaly, i just see "Please follow these steps to set up and start using your website" block in content.

Comment: Why not give it a try by updating all the files again and running update.php? May be you missed something when upgrading!

Comment: So i went true all again but no affect, could it be a problem with update module?

Comment: Nop! You can do one thing, go to /modules/node and open the node.info file check the Drupal version in it! This is the best way to check it.

Comment: Here is what i see there: name = Node
description = Allows content to be submitted to the site and displayed on pages.
package = Core - required
version = VERSION
core = 6.x

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2013-01-16
version = "6.28"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1358370963" So i guees it's ok?

Comment: Yes, it is! Please navigate to update.php and try to run the db update. Also check apache and Drupal logs for any clue!